# using inputText as f:parm of an outputLink

Tags: jsf

In JSF 1.1, is it possible to use value of inputText as f:parm of an outputLink?
For example:

```
<h:inputText value="enter Input Value" />
<h:outputLink value="someLink.jsp"  styleClass="searchButton">
    <f:param name="userName" value="whatever the input value is" />
</h:outputLink>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with standard JSF. You'd need to bring in some JavaScript code.

E.g.

```
<h:form id="formId">
    <h:inputText id="inputId" />
    <h:outputLink value="someLink.jsp?userName=" onclick="href+=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('formId:inputId').value)" />
</h:form>
```

An alternative is to just use a plain vanilla HTML.

```
<f:verbatim>
    <form action="someLink.jsp">
         <input type="text" name="userName" />
         <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</f:verbatim>
```

You could if necessary add some CSS to make the button to look like a link.

Comment: The reason for using outputLink is because I've a few other f:parm that do not involve inputText.  Here is the actual outputlink:  <h:outputLink value="userDirectory.jsf"><f:param name="acctID" value="#{userDirectoryListBean.nonLoginAcctID }" /><f:param name="listFrom" value="#{userDirectoryListBean.listFrom}" /><f:param name="searchValue" value="whatever the input" /></h:outputLink>

Comment: Thanks Balus, I think the first method you provided will work.  I just have to play around with it to make sure it does not interfere with other f:parm